# Row locking behaviour while updating

Tags: sql-server, locking

In Oracle databases I can start a transaction and update a row without committing. Selecting this row in another session still returns the current ("old") value.

How to get this behaviour in SQL Server? Currently, the row is locked until the transaction is ended. WITH (NOLOCK) inside the select statement gives the new value from the uncommitted transaction which is potentially dangerous.

Starting the transaction without committing:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
UPDATE test SET val = 'Updated' WHERE id = 1;
```

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = 2;
```

This waits for the transaction to be committed:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: I will openly admit this isn't my area of expertise in SQL Server, but I suspect you want to be looking at [Snapshot isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server).

Comment: Adding to the other comments, `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON` is the default for Azure SQL database but not for on-prem.  Alternatively, you could turn on `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` and then opt in as desired with `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: Thanks for the tid-bit on the default difference on Azure SQL Databases, @DanGuzman , if true that explains some behaviour I saw a couple of years ago in an application that was using one, where it looked like it was using the value prior to an `UPDATE`; because it possibly was!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (RCSI), versions of rows are stored in a version store, so readers can read a version of a row that existed at the time the statement started and before any changes have been made; while a transaction is open; without taking shared locks on rows or pages; and without blocking writers or other readers. From [this post by Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation):

> To summarize, locking read committed sees each row as it was at the time it was briefly locked and physically read; RCSI sees all rows as they were at the time the statement began. Both implementations are guaranteed to never see uncommitted data,

One cost, of course, is that if you read a prior version of the row, it can change (even many times) before you're done doing whatever it is you plan to do with it. If you're making important decisions based on some past version of the row, it may be the case that you actually *want* an isolation level that forces you to wait until all changes have been committed.

Another cost is that version store is not free... it requires space and I/O in tempdb, so if tempdb is already a bottleneck on your system, this is something worth testing.

(In SQL Server 2019, with [Accelerated Database Recovery](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5971/accelerated-database-recovery-in-sql-server-2019/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), the version store shifts to the user database, which increases database size but mitigates some of the tempdb contention.)

[Paul's post](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation) goes on to explain some other risks and caveats.

In almost all cases, this is still way better than `NOLOCK`, IMHO. Lots of links about the dangers there (and why RCSI is better) here:

- [I'm using NOLOCK; is that bad?](https://sqlblog.org/nolock)

And finally, [from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide) (adding one clarification from the comments):

> When the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option is set ON, read committed isolation uses row versioning to provide statement-level read consistency. Read operations require only SCH-S table level locks and no page or row locks. That is, the SQL Server Database Engine uses row versioning to present each statement with a transactionally consistent snapshot of the data as it existed at the start of the statement. Locks are not used to protect the data from updates by other transactions. A user-defined function can return data that was committed after the time the statement containing the UDF began.
> When the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option is set OFF, which is the default setting * ***on-prem but not in Azure SQL Database*** *, read committed isolation uses shared locks to prevent other transactions from modifying rows while the current transaction is running a read operation. The shared locks also block the statement from reading rows modified by other transactions until the other transaction is completed. Both implementations meet the ISO definition of read committed isolation.

Comment: Also note that with READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT enabled SQL Server's READ COMMITTED behaves like Oracle's READ COMMITTED, and SQL Server's SNAPSHOT behaves like Oracle's SERIALIZABLE.